# Angularjs dropdown is closed due to ng-focus event

Tags: angularjs, html

I have a form in Angularjs. I have a dropdown in form as:

```
   <p ng-show="isCompoValMsgOn">'select component'</p>
    <select ng-focus="onFocusComponent($event)"   id="component" ng-model="component.selected" ng-change="onSelectComponentCode()">
   <option value="">Select Component</option>
   <option ng-repeat="component   in  list value="{{component}}">{{ component.DES }}</option>
   </select>
```

If user click on the save button without selecting any component then I am showing the error by setting the `isCompoValMsgOn=true`:

```
$scope.isCompoValMsgOn=true
```

Now I want that as soon as users focus on dropdown the error message should hide. For this I have write the code:

```
$scope.onFocusComponent = function ($event) {
        $scope.isCompoValMsgOn = false; 
    }
```

This is working but creating another issue.

**The problem is here :**
As soon as I focus on the dropdown error message hides but the dropdown is also closed and random option is selected.

**But my requirement is below :**

1. Error message should hide
2. drop down should not be closed and let the user select the option

Comment: Try ng-if="!isCompoValMsgOn"

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I have tried still the same problem occures

Answer (score 0):

Here is your problem:

```
<option ng-repeat="component in list" value="{{component.DES}}">{{ component.DES }}</option>
```

Missing quote mark

Answer (score 0):

I have find the solution of the above problem.I have use the ng-click event instead of the ng-focus event.Here is the code :

```
<select ng-click="onFocusComponent()" ng-disabled="!frmValidationParms.IsCepCodeSelected" class="form-control" name="component" id="component" ng-model="component.selected" ng-change="onSelectComponentCode()">
                                <option value="">Select Component</option>
                                <option ng-repeat="component   in component.projectListData.PCAT_OBJ.ARR_PCOM | orderBy:['ORD']" value="{{component}}">{{ component.DES }}</option>
                            </select>
```